# How to encrypt and use a symmetric key with an asymmetric key pair

Tags: encryption, rsa, private-key

I have messages I need to be able to encrypt when being sent. They should only be able to be decrypted by the receiver.

Initially, I had a structure where the message is encrypted using the receiver's public key, and the receiver then uses their private key to decrypt their messages. However, since I was using RSA, the size of the message was quite limited.

I'm imagining two potential solutions, but am not quite sure how to implement the better one (option 2).

1. (Easy) just split up each message into many smaller parts, encrypt and store those. This would only change the query structure of my app but not the encryption structure.
2. I could encrypt the messages with symmetric keys, which is faster and works on any size. However, I would then need to encrypt that symmetric key with an asymmetric one. The problem then becomes that I can only decrypt the symmetric key when the asymmetric private one is provided, ie when the receiver wants to read their messages. So in that case, how would I actually encrypt the messages? Since I don't want the sender to be able to access a key used for decryption as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem then becomes that I can only decrypt the symmetric key when the asymmetric private one is provided, ie when the receiver wants to read their messages. So in that case, how would I actually encrypt the messages?

That's simple, you use an ephemeral, message specific, fully random symmetric key for data encryption *before* you encrypt it with the public key. Preferably you should explicitly destroy the symmetric key after that. You can prefix the wrapped (encrypted) symmetric key before the ciphertext of the message, as it will always have the same size in bytes as the modulus (i.e. the RSA key size in bytes).

The system you are thinking about, which is much better than splitting up messages for RSA, is called a *hybrid cryptosystem*. There are various other ways to accomplish the same thing such as RSA-KEM and - for elliptic curves - ECIES. Both are not often present in crypto-libraries though.

If you decide to use RSA/AES for *sending* cryptograms then I would advice you to use OAEP and e.g. AES-CTR rather than AES-CBC as RSA PKCS#1 v1.5 padding and CBC padding are both vulnerable to padding oracle attacks.

---

It is highly recommended to *sign* the messages, otherwise an adversary can encrypt fake messages. Encryption is only used to achieve message confidentiality, not message integrity & authenticity. An adversary may even try *plaintext oracle attacks* if any message can be send. If you are not allowing a set of private keys that *you control* then you should *sign-then-encrypt*, not *encrypt-then-sign*.

And as always, prefer TLS or other explicit secure transport protocols if that's an option for transport security.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204795/discussion-on-answer-by-maarten-reinstate-monica-how-to-encrypt-and-use-a-symm).